# does a code signing certificate help with false positive from a virus scanner

Tags: c#, windows, code-signing, antivirus, virus

We have a piece of code in c# that is identified as a virus by AVG under it's heuristic behavioral detection. We've been in contact with them to find out why but they haven't been responsive. Currently all our dll's and exe's are signed with a certificate we generated (won't be in the trusted store) does anyone know if we purchase a Code signing cert whether that will help in regards to the false positive?

Comment: Most likely not, because this certificate doesn't change the behavior of your software and that's what is analyzed by the anti virus software.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We purchased a code-signing certificate and we still got flagged by Symantec so it's no guarantee. In the end we contacted their white-listing service and they eventually got back to us to say our app had checked out and it would be whitelisted. Never had to deal with AVG so can't comment on their process (or lack of).

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, I'd say no. If signing your code was all it took to get past antivirus software, then a few hundred bucks would be enough to make all antivirus software completely useless. A code signing certificate certifies that the code comes from you, not that it is not malicious.

Comment: @maddO that makes sense, but there is also the view that someone who is willing to be identified is less likely to try and harm your computer.

Comment: I don't even need few hundred bucks. Whenever I send any app to some antivirus company, they whitelist the app without any questions.